# What is the Time Complexity of my algorithm?

Tags: python, python-3.x, time-complexity

This algorithm was written for LeetCode's climbing stairs problem and it ran at 20ms. I believe the time complexity is O(n), because this link https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-time-complexity-with-python-examples-2bda6e8158a7 said O(n) is when the running time increases linearly as the size of the input gets bigger, which is what I think is going on here.

I was wondering if someone could explain to me the the time complexity here and why it would be that. Any additional info on how I could get it to linear time if I'm not there already would help too.

Here is my code:

```
class Solution:
    def climbStairs(self, n: int) -> int:
        if n == 0: return 1

        else:
            temp = []

            for i in range(0, n + 1):
                temp.append(i)
                if temp[i] == 0:
                    temp[i] = 1
                elif temp[i] > 1:
                    temp[i] = temp[i-1] + temp[i-2]

            return temp[-1]
```

Comment: Why do you use `1*cells`?

Comment: I see now. That is pointless.

Comment: What is the algorithm?

Comment: It solves the climbing stairs problem on Leet Code. Here is the link to the problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/climbing-stairs/ @AMC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A constant amount of work is done for each iteration (assuming `append` takes constant time); there are N iterations, hence O(n) time.